# Error when trying to execute Qt app from shared library

Tags: c++, qt, java-native-interface

I am trying to execute simple Qt app from other languages (target is Java). 
My app looks like this:

```
  //HelloWorld.pro
  TEMPLATE= lib
  TARGET = HelloWorld
  QT = core gui widgets
  SOURCES += main.cpp
```

c++ source

```
   //main.cpp
   #include <QApplication>

   int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
       QApplication app (argc, argv);
       return app.exec();
   }
```

I compiled it with qmake and make but everytime I try to load shared library I get Segmentation fault 11.

```
 //PS: simplest code in python to load shared library
 from ctypes import *
 cdll.LoadLibrary('libHelloWorld.dylib').main()
```

I don't know where's the problem.

PS: My goal is to interact with Qt5 in Java through JNI/JNA

Comment: When executing with JNA: #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000011cd989ca, pid=10582, tid=3335   # Problematic frame:
# C  [QtGui+0x1e9ca]  QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration()+0x1ea

Comment: Libraries don't have `main` entry point. You probably want to read https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/sites/default/files/BogdanVatra_Extending_Qt_Android_Apps_with_JNI.pdf and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html

Comment: Runtime error aside, main function aside -- why are you starting an event loop in a library? This just isn't an intended use case for QApplication.

Comment: @svlasov I don't want to execute Java from C++, I want the opposite.

Comment: I just want to launch and interact with Qt GUI in Java. My goal is to achieve the same as qt-jambi but for Qt5